# Select a list of records from a database and display in a form - c#

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to create a receipt and would like to have each product name and cost listed to show the customer what they have bought, and eventually will include quantity as well.

I would like to select the product name and cost from the database, for each product, and display each product with its cost.

I couldn't get this to work as it kept showing the last product which was in the transaction - how can i get all the products in the transaction?

If you have any questions on what i am trying to do, just ask and i will answer.

```
SqlCommand searchProduct = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT ProductName, Cost FROM dbo.NCAProduct WHERE ProductCode = " + productCode, sqlConnect);
    try
    {
        //sqlConnect.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr4 = searchProduct.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr4.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr4.Read())
            {
                label10.Text = dr4["ProductName"].ToString() + " ";
                label13.Text = dr4["Cost"].ToString() + " ";
            }
        }
        dr4.Close();
    }
    catch (SqlException error2)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(error2.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: `label13.Text = dr4["Cost"].ToString() + " ";` will replace the text every time so of course the last one on the list is the last one to stay in the label

Comment: What could i use to get around this?

Comment: You simply overwrite the content of `label10` and `label13` for every row returned from your query. By definition the last row will be the one that is displayed. What do you expect your code to do?

Comment: I want it do display each row which is selected

Comment: Then display your data in a grid or add more labels.

Comment: is there a way i could put the labels in a loop to create when an extra row is selected - as there could be an unlimited number of rows selected

Answer (score 0):

Define Product class

```
public Product
{
    public ProductName{get;set;}
    public Cost{get;set;}
}
```

When you retrieve data from the database use this:

```
         public List<Product> GetProductList() 
         {
                    //sqlConnect.Open();
                    SqlDataReader dr4 = searchProduct.ExecuteReader();

                    List <Product> products = new List<Product>();
                    //your method should return products

                    if (dr4.HasRows)
                    {

                        while (dr4.Read())
                        {
                             Product myP = new Product();

                             myP.ProductName = dr4["ProductName"].ToString() + " ";
                             myP.Cost = dr4["Cost"].ToString() + " ";

                             Products.Add(myP);

                        }
                    }
                    dr4.Close();

                     return products;

      }
```

In your web form, insert a gridview and name as grd_Products. Then bind the products to the gridview as indicated below:

```
grd_Products.DataSource = GetProductList();//this returns the List<Products>
grd_Products.DataBind();
```

If you do not want to use grid:

```
foreach(Product p in products) { //you can get p.ProductName or p.Cost of each product here and print them on the screen}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As noted above in the comments, you're label text is being overwritten each time and will therefore only show the last item. If you want to show a long list of items then it would be best to use a datatable to store your items. If you're using asp.net you can then bind to a gridview to display them rather than a label. Below is how you could use a datatable:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataColumn c = new DataColumn();

c.DataType = typeof(string);
c.Name = "Product Name";
dt.Columns.Add(c);

c = new DataColumn();
c.DataType = typeof(decimal);
c.Name = "Cost";
dt.Columns.Add(c);

while (dr4.Read())
{
    DataRow r = dt.NewRow();
    r["Product Name"] = dr4["ProductName"].ToString();
    r["Cost"] = dr4["Cost"].ToString();

    dt.Rows.Add(r);
}
```

If you're desperate to use labels, though I can't see why you would be in this case (unlimited number of rows selected and all that) you could create a new label for each product and add it to a panel on your aspx page.

```
while (dr4.Read())
{
    Label MyLabel = new Label();
    MyLabel = dr4["ProductName"].ToString() + " ";
    MyLabel += dr4["Cost"].ToString();

    MyPanel.Controls.Add(MyLabel);
}
```

To use this you would need to create a panel on your aspx page (in this case called MyPanel) to add your labels to. To add styles and such then you can either do it at the time of creating the new label or apply a class to the label and add a style using css to labels with that class.

Comment: I am trying to not use a grid view as it is for an onscreen receipt - and thought labels would look more realistic

Comment: @user3461835 - how would labels be "more realistic" than a gridview? A gridview is versatile enough for this purpose (in most cases) and would come with a whole load of additional functionality that you may wish to use, such as paging, sorting etc.

Comment: @user3461835  - did any of this help?